# Using table of Laplace transforms for t>0 to calculate functions defined on t<0

Tags: laplace-transform

I've noticed that it's often true that if:
$$\mathcal{L}(f(t)\theta(t)) = F(s), \qquad Re(s)>0$$
then:
$$\mathcal{L}(f(t)(\theta(t) - 1)) = F(s), \qquad Re(s)<0$$
For example it is true for $f(t)=sin(at)$

But is this a general rule?

If it where it would mean that if we have a table of Laplace transforms for functions defined on $(0,\infty)$ we could use the same table of one-sided transforms for functions defined on $(-\infty,0)$, as long as we multiply the function we want to transform by $-1$ first.